# CSS layout changes when i resize browser. I've only been coding for a few weeks and have hit a brick wall

Tags: html, css

Hi I've looked on W3 and here but cant find answer. I've achieved the layout I want, but it falls apart when i start to resize the browser. I've been coding for six weeks. Why won't the layout behave?

```css
  div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#head {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="head"> The Daily Scumbag</div>
<div id="left">
  <h1>This is left column.
  </h1>
  Lorem Vestibulum
</div>
<div id="right">
```

Comment: Try to search for `responsive`.

Comment: Im on it now Patrick. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your basic idea was good, but you got some things not ideal here.

I think you know for yourself that manually setting one div to `width: 47%;` and the other one to `49%` is not ideal. I guess you want `50%` each. You do not need `display:inline-block;` in this case when you want to use `float`.

More important, for easier css management, I would add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your div css declaration. It prevents the border and the padding from being added ontop of the width and ensures that you can use `width: 50%;` accordingly (read more on this here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

See this updated example here:

```
<style>
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#head {
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;


}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#footer {
    clear:left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

A note to:

```
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

This prevents Browsers from using their default values, this removes the space you have around your elements and the browser window.

Comment: You can see the way i was thinking! Your box-sizing suggestion worked perfectly!!

Comment: You can set the answer that solved your problem to "solved" by checking the checkbox left to that answer. It turns green. Above this checkbox you can see the rating buttons to rate an answer. More on this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [box-sizing: border-box;](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) on the floating element to include padding and border. Padding and border are added to the width.

```css
  div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#head {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="head"> The Daily Scumbag</div>
<div id="left">
  <h1>This is left column.
  </h1>
  Lorem Vestibulum
</div>
<div id="right">
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you need to write the responsive code where webpage automatically adjusts to the size of the browser. You can achieve this with the help of the twitter bootstrap.

All the best.